# How to properly add image in Windows 8 store app (C#/XAML)

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Here's the line of where I have my image added to the XAML mark up:

```
<Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Source="Assets/default.png"></Image>
```

Now for some reason, I can't get it to show. It won't show when I run the App and it won't show on the XAML Design layout tool either.

Are there any problems that I am may or may not be going through? I'm pretty sure my XAML correctly written (unless I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I have to literally drag and drop the image file into the Solution explorer in the according folder. I was using visual studio, in case if any one wants to know.